# Какие данные заносить в state? React

Tags: reactjs

Какие данные следует заносить в состояние компонента, а какие - нет?

Например, есть **таблица** с **фильтром**, есть переменная `_maxPage`, хранящая кол-во отображённых ячеек таблицы при выборе фильтра.
Есть переменная-буфер для таблицы, дабы не изменять начальные данные при фильтрации.

Что из перечисленного хранить в состоянии компонента, и почему?
Правильно ли понимаю, что только таблицу и фильтр, а буфер и `_maxPage` можно объявить вообще за пределами классового компонента и изменять в процессе выполнения кода?

Comment: Все реактивные переменные которые рендерятся в jsx хранить в стейте, остальные не реактивные переменные можно хранить вне компонента.  Хотя конечно это будет солянка и сложно разбираться, по этому я бы все хранил в стейте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стейте я храню минимум -- то, что не вычисляется из чего-то еще.

Стейт меняется акшном. Из стейта вычисляется всё
, что можно, на рендере.
Тяжелые вычисления мемоизируются.

Значения в фильтре, данные с сервера, текущая страница (для набора значений) -- выглядит как стейт.

Для того, что за пределами, не будет работать ререндер. По умолчанию я бы так не делал. Только в качестве своевременной оптимизации.

Comment: функция , которая вычисляет что-то из стейта, может быть описана и вне компонента, если она **чистая** (ничего сама не хранит)